# Does Jenkins support incremental pipeline builds?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, incremental-build

I have been searching far and wide to see if I can find information on Jenkins incremental pipeline builds that does not involve Maven.

The general idea is that I want to build a generic project and run specific steps of the pipeline if the underlying code has changed. If the code did not change, I want to re-use the results from a previous build.

The reason why I want to do this, is to drastically reduce build times for huge projects.

Imagine that you only need to fix 1 line in a SCSS file, but the whole project needs to be rebuild, repackaged, etc because of this. In the meantime, the site is live and broken and waiting 15 mins to be fixed.

Can someone give a basic example of how such a build can be created or where I can find more information on incremental building?

The only thing I have been able to find is incremental building for Maven projects, but this is not applicable for me.

Comment: did you try something ? What a build tool do use?

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution is to create modules that depends on each others.

Publish the built artifact of your modules to a binary repository like Sonatype Nexus (you can easily create private npm repo as well as proxy npm repo).

During the build download the dependencies, instead of building them.

---

If this solution is not the one you want to take, you will have a hard time hacking a solution. To persist the state of your steps, an easy solution is to create files in the job workspace and read them at next build